# カレント以下のファイルの中身をまとめて見る方法

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

カレント以下のファイルの中身すべてをまとめてみたいです。一つひとつ確認するのが大変だからです。catなどつかってみれるのでしょうか？

Comment: Linux であれば GNU grep の `-I` オプション(`--binary-files=without-match`)を使って `grep -rIl -e '.' | xargs cat | less` とする事もできます。ただ、文字コードの問題がありそうなので、nkf コマンドがインストールされているのであれば `grep -rIl -e '.' | xargs nkf -w | less` とする方が良さそうです。

Comment: @metropolis 過去にも何度かお伝えしていますが、**質問への回答** は [コメント欄ではなく実際の回答として投稿してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) 。

Answer (score 2):

一番シンプルな方法は **ページャ** の `more` や `less` を使えばよいのかなと思います。
(対象のディレクトリにテキストとして表示できるファイルのみが存在すると仮定した場合)

```
$ more *.txt
   or
$ less *.txt
```

`more` はファイルの終端に来たら自動で次のファイルに移動します。
`less` の場合は `:n` で次のファイルへ移動します。

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f | xargs tail -n +1
```

や

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

が良さそうです。

## 参考資料

[cat - How to display contents of all files under a directory on the screen using unix commands - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277963/how-to-display-contents-of-all-files-under-a-directory-on-the-screen-using-unix)

[command line - Show contents of many files - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/show-contents-of-many-files)

Answer (score 1):

zshですと、 `**` で複数段のディレクトリにもマッチするワイルドカードが書けるので、たとえば

```
$ wc **/*.h
```

とやると、カレント以下の奥深い所にあるものも含めて、 "*.h" なファイルだけ wcすることができます。

[以下投稿後編集]
ファイルの中身を単純に表示するのであれば、catはもちろん、moreやlessなどのコマンドも使えます。

Comment: `wc` コマンドだと、ファイルの中身は確認できないのではないでしょうか？ (単語数や行数を表示するコマンドなため)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コマンドの一例として書きましたが、どうせ書くならば元の質問に直接対応する例を挙げた方が親切でしたね。

Answer (score 1):

ファイル名、行番号付きで表示するなら`pr`がよいと思います。

```
find . -type f | xargs pr -n -f | less
```

```
find . -name "*.c" | xargs pr -n -f | less
```

Comment: ひとつひとつ確認するのが大変な大量のファイルを、ひとまとめにして(巨大がデータにして)見るというのは、辛くないですか？　類似した内容のファイルが複数あると、どのファイルを見ているのかさえ分らなくなりかねないように思います。

Comment: ケースバイケースだと思います。大量のファイルを概観するときには、全部まとめて確認したいことはよくあります。質問された方が同じような調べ方をすることを考え回答しました。lessの検索機能を使えばどのファイルなのかを確認することも容易です。